# How to get UITextField Tap Event?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios-universal-app

I am trying to show UIAlertView on Tap or Click of UITextField for both IPad and IPhone. I make an IBAction and Attach it with Tap Down event of UITextField.

But its not working correctly, means not always, in case of iphone and not working in-case of iPad

```
- (IBAction) TopuchState
{
    //function code
}
```

please help How could I do this.

[image]

Comment: Touch Up Inside? Did you tried that one?

Comment: if your textfield is inside scrollview then uncheck delay content touches in inspect property for scroll view. It should work then.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try adding a target for when a particular text field begins editing (`UIControlEventEditingDidBegin`):

```
 [textField1 addTarget:delegate action:@selector(textField1Active:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
```

Comment: I was so tired of posts asking how to dismiss the keyboard by tapping outside the textfield....thanks a bunch! (I used UIControlEventAllTouchEvents)

Answer (score 28):

As you are already subscribed to be UITextField delegate, implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Alert Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have almost 8-9 UITextFields on View and in iPad control's tags are also not working if you match which UITextFields's event got fire.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's easier if you set the delegate for the `UITextField` and implement the method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

then inside that method you can easily create and show your `UIAlertView`.

Take a look at [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate).

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

**In Swift 3**

Add a target for a particular text field for the event .editingDidBegin in viewDidLoad method

```
self.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldTouched(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin)

func textFieldTouched(textField: UITextField) {
//Show AlertView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Connect TextField with delegate and Now calling this function!!

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {       
   textView.text=@"   ";
   return YES;
}
```