# On click of a UITextField, I want to run some code

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a UITextField with an outlet called newscore.  I am trying to run a block of code when the UITextfield (particularly newscore) is tapped and the keyboard is brought up, or when the user is begin editing the UITextfield.

I can't seem to figure out the proper function to do this.. Is it similar to the code below (the code doesn't work) or is the function called something else?

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

//Run block of code

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get UITextField Tap Event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045095/how-to-get-uitextfield-tap-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is correct.

If it is not being called, just check that text field delegate correct

Answer (score 2):

It's the right function. You need to set the delegate of your field like that:

```
yourTextfield.delegate = self
```

Also you need to set the Delegate in your class like that:

```
class YourClass : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

Answer (score 1):

The functions

```
textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
```

which returns a Bool, or

```
textFieldDidBeginEditing:
```

are precisely what you want. All you need to do is make this class that your code is running in conform to the [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html) protocol, which is done by writing

```
class TheClass: PossibleSuperclass, PossibleProtocol, UITextFieldDelegate {...
```

and then officially set the delegate of the textfield to be your class either by using

```
theTextfield.delegate = self
```

in some startup/initialisation code, or by making a "delegate" outlet from the textfield to the class object in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
    }
    
}
```