# How to detect cursor did NOT change on click of UITextField in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, key-value-observing

I know you can subscribe to the selectedTextRange with KVO to determine when the cursor changes in UITextField so that when I click a different location, the cursor changes and the event is fired.

BUT if I click on the same exact cursor position, it doesn't trigger this event (because I guess selectedTextRange is not actually being set, its remaining the same). How do I detect when they click **on the exact same cursor spot** or rather when a keystroke is happening but **the cursor position does not change**. Not a text change but a 'non-cursor change'.

Thank you!

Comment: I think this will help solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814697/uitapgesturerecognizer-tap-on-self-view-but-ignore-subviews You need to use the gesture delegate and some logic to decide if the touch was a no change touch or not.

Comment: This may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045095/how-to-get-uitextfield-tap-event